# django admin and inlines

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am having a weird behaviour when I add a booleanfield to a through memebership which is included as an inline into the main model. Once saved, it randomly shows the field as True/False. No matter what's on the DB.

```
class Project(models.Model):
    # Relations with other entities.
    employees = models.ManyToManyField('staff.Person', through='project.PersonProjectMembership',
                                       related_name='projects')
class PersonProjectMembership(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey('project.Project', related_name="person_memberships")
    person = models.ForeignKey('staff.Person', related_name="project_memberships")
    lead = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class ProjectAdmin(TranslationAdmin, ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (PersonProjectMembershipInline,)

class PersonProjectMembershipInline(TranslationStackedInline, admin.StackedInline):
    model = Project.employees.through
    extra = 1
    formset = PersonProjectMembershipInlineFormSet

class PersonProjectMembershipInlineFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        # [...]
```

Any idea?

Comment: where is the boolean field you are mentioning?

Comment: I just forgot to add the "through" class. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the same object is being retrieved each time? Since there is no ordering specified, it could be different objects. Hence the discrepancy

Comment: Yes, same project and same employee, but different values for the property "lead". And I have the same issue with other "through" models...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while already. The problem was in some validator, where I was overwriting the PersonProjectMembership.lead value.